# Azure DevOps wiki with mathematical formulas prints strikethrough instead of a fraction

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I used this mathematical formula syntax in DevOps wiki to write fractions

```
$$\frac{233}{x_i}$$
```

In DevOps preview it works well and looks like this:

[image: preview in Azure DevOps]

But once I print it into PDF, the fraction becomes a strikethrough like this:

[image: print in PDF]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do by yourself.

I would recommend to open a bug report here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem

I could reproduce it myself. They answer quickly and can fix it pretty quickly (sometimes some days, sometimes in the next sprint)

Comment: UPD:
It is fixed already and should be deployed soon. See feedback ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ADO-Wiki-cannot-render-fractions-properl/10495582?sort=newest&topics=visual+studio+2019&WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5003763